# How do I upgrade python version in airflow?

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

For context I deployed in GKE a managed Kubernetes cluster version 1.27.2-gke.1200 and then I installed airflow using the helm charts which installed Airflow 2.6.2. I didn't specify any versions or anything.

I want to run python modules in my DAGs and DAG instantiations that are only available in 3.8 but when I kubectl exec into my webserver or scheduler pods I noticed that they use python version 3.7. How do I change the python version that airflow can use?

I've looked into this website link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.1/installation.html#constraints-files and found details on the constraints files but I'm not sure how to deploy it and how to install a different python version.

Would I need to go into each pod in my airflow cluster and install the right python version?